# Rule engine for User notification

Tags: notifications, rule-engine

There are event Object which will have following properties:

1. Type = can take A, B, C etc as values
2. Source = can take X, Y, Z etc as values
3. status = 1, 2, 3 etc as values

Now there can be several users. Each one can register for different conditions to receive notifications when an event is received.

The condition can be:

- `type = A` alone ,
- `type = A and Source = X and status -3`,
- or `type = C or status = 3 and source = z`.

I can handle it in Java but is there any simple framwork which can handle it.

I searched on Google and there are plenty of framework which gives an idea on how to apply conditions but I was not able to see how to correlate to users.

Do I need to apply the conditions given for each users for each event. Is there any smart condition pooling mechanism through which I can get the target users with less iterations.

Appreciate any pointers.